# How to replace whitespace with notepad++ between two characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have question how to replace whitespace with _ using notepad++ regex between [] characters

Example :

```
sl.[Posting date]                       AS TIME, 
'0000-00-00'                            AS edate, 
sl.[Document No_], 
[Original Currency Factor]
```

Result

```
sl.[Posting_date]                       AS TIME, 
'0000-00-00'                            AS edate, 
sl.[Document_No_], 
[Original_Currency_Factor]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Find what: `[.+(\s)+.+]`

Replace with: `_`

Also don't forget to select `Regular expression` radio button in `Search mode` section.

**Update:**

Ok, I have one solution but it's dirty:

You need to perform several replacements to do that.

Find what: `(\[.*)\s(.*\])`

Replace with: `\1_\2`

Repeat using `Replace all` until there will be no occurrences.

Comment: Working bad, replace whitespaces between all characters:)

Comment: \s matches all space like chars, including tabs, which should stay intact

Answer (score 0):

Use

Regex Replace

```
(\[[^ ]*) +(.*\])
```

with

```
$1_$2
```

if you want to replace multiple space character with a single _ 
OR

Regex Replace

```
(\[[^ ]*) (.*\])
```

with

```
$1_$2
```

if you want to replace each space character with a single _

Answer (score 0):

To replace chunks of whitespace between square brackets, you can use

```
(?:\G(?!^(?<!.))|\[)[^][\s]*\K\s+(?=[^][]*])
```

And a bonus same solution for replacing whitespaces in between round brackets/parentheses:

```
(?:\G(?!^(?<!.))|\()[^()\s]*\K\s+(?=[^()]*\))
```

Replace with `_` or any other char you need. **NOTE**: *`.` matches newline* option must be ENABLED. Or, prepend the regex with `(?s)`, `(?s)(?:\G(?!^(?<!.))|\[)[^][\s]*\K\s+(?=[^][]*])`.

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^(?<!.))|\[)` - end of the previous successful match (see `\G(?!^(?<!.))`, [`\G` matches](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) start of a file or end of previous match, that is why `(?!^(?<!.))` negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is added to exclude the position at the start of a file, it makes sure the current position is not a start of a line that has no more chars immedately on the left) or (`|`) a `[` char (`\[`)
- `[^][\s]*` - zero or more chars other than `]`, `[` and whitespace
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that discards all text matched so far from the overall mathc memory buffer
- `\s+` - *one or more* whitespaces (**NOTE** that if you want to replace *each* whitespace with `_` separately, remove `+`)
- `(?=[^][]*])` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]` immediately to the right of the current location.

See the demo screenshot & settings:

[image]